# all solutions to change making with dynamic programming

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I was reviewing my handouts for our algorithm class and I started to think about this question:

**Given different types of coins with different values, find all coin configurations to add up to a certain sum without duplication.**

During class, we solved the problem to find the number of all possible ways for a sum and the least number of coins for a sum. However, we never tried to actually find the solutions.

I was thinking about solving this problem with dynamic programming.

I came with the recursion version(for simplicity I only print the solutions):

```
void solve(vector<string>& result, string& currSoln, int index, int target, vector<int>& coins)
{
    if(target < 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(target == 0)
    {
        result.push_back(currSoln);
    }

    for(int i = index; i < coins.size(); ++i)
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << coins[i];
        string newCurrSoln = currSoln + ss.str() + " ";
        solve(result, newCurrSoln, i, target - coins[i], coins);
    }
}
```

However, I got stuck when trying to use DP to solve the problem.
I have 2 major obstacles:

1. I don't know what data structure I should use to store previous answers
2. I don't know what my bottom-up procedure(using loops to replace recursions) should look like.

Any help is welcomed and some codes would be appreciated!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me if you can use dynamic programming for this problem.  If I'm finding 50cents, add one quarter, and "recurse" on 25cents, which finds 1 quarter and 5 nickles.  Then I go back to the start, try 5 nickles, and check the results of 25cents, which finds the aforcalculated 2 solutions, so I say there are 4 total solutions.  But 1 quarter+5nickles and 5nickles+1 quarter are duplicates.

Comment: There can be exponentially many possible solutions to change-making, so DP will help but might still take a really, really long time to complete. Are you okay with that?

Comment: I wrote a naive version to compare against: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2c06ff6aa2ea45a

Comment: Did you even look for "change making" on google?

Comment: yes. I did. Most of them are only "mini number of coins" and "total number of ways". Few actually bother to find all the solutions but none of them uses DP. I welcome constructive comments but simply asking me if I googled is not helpful......If you can give me a link to where you found the solution I would appreciate it.@tmyklebu

Comment: Yeah. I just want to know the DP version of the solution. I know finding all solutions is a complex problem in its nature. My primary concern with recursion is that if you have a large sum you might get stack overflow.(well....using DP might eat all your memories...but whatever...) @templatetypedef

Answer (score 1):

In a dp solution you generate a set of intermediate states, and how many ways there are to get there.  Then your answer is the number that wound up in a success state.

So, for change counting, the states are that you got to a specific amount of change.  The counts are the number of ways of making change.  And the success state is that you made the correct amount of change.

To go from counting solutions to enumerating them you need to keep those intermediate states, and also keep a record in each state of all of the states that transitioned to that one - and information about how.  (In the case of change counting, the how would be which coin you added.)

Now with that information you can start from the success state and recursively go **backwards** through the dp data structures to actually find the solutions rather than the count.  The good news is that all of your recursive work is efficient - you're always only looking at paths that succeed so waste no time on things that won't work.  But if there are a billion solutions, then there is no royal shortcut that makes printing out a billion solutions fast.

If you wish to be a little clever, though, you can turn this into a usable enumeration.  You can, for instance, say "I know there are 4323431 solutions, what is the 432134'th one?"  And finding that solution will be quick.

Comment: so what you mean is basically. In addition to a 2D array dp[i][j] where i is the remaining amount and j is the type of coin, I still need to have another data structure to store what coin I took when I go from one state to another. That way when I finish count the number of all possible ways, I can brute-force, starting from the finish state and try to find all solutions recursively. Is this basically what you are saying?

Comment: @TianyuLang Sounds like you got it.  It would do to add a linked list of which other states you arrived at a state from, and add to it every time you arrive at a state.

Answer (score 0):

It is immediately obvious that you can take a dynamic programming approach. What isn't obvious that in most cases (depending on the denominations of the coins) you can use the greedy algorithm, which is likely to be more efficient. See Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein: Introduction to Algorithms 2nd ed, problems 16.1.

Comment: yeah. using greedy would be way more efficient but it is not a general solution. Since it would fail if the type of coins you have is "particular"