# Generate random bridge hands with a certain strength

Tags: algorithm, random

I am trying to make a java program that deals bridge hands (13 cards from a standard 52 card pack) with a certain number of high hards (Aces, Kings, Queens, and Jacks) in each hand.

I was looking at the question posed in the following post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3205/choosing-subsets-of-a-set-such-that-the-subsets-satisfy-a-global-constraint, addapted below:

---

We have a set of items C = cards in a standard 52 card deck.  Each of these items has what we call a *p* value: aces a strength of 4, kings a strength of 3, queens 2, jacks 1, and all other cards 0. We want to choose a subset of C, the bridge hand with 13 cards, such that the sum of the *p* values of the items in the hand exceeds 12. Moreover, we want to do this efficiently.

We hope to do this in O(n) time, but any polynomial time algorithm is good enough.  We certainly do not want to just try every possible subset of C of size 13 and then check whether it satisfies the p-value constraint.

---

The problem goes on to say that we want the subsets chosen to be a uniformly random distribution over all the possible such subsets, but the solution says that this is NP-complete. However what if I don't need the distribution of selected subsets of cards to be perfectly uniform? It would be good enough for me to have an approximate solution that feels random. Is there an algorithm to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As phrased in the linked question, the problem is NP-complete because the "P values" of the inputs are allowed to be arbitrary, so that it is not even clear that the constraint is satisfiable. Producing bridge hands of a range of HCP is not the same problem.

The usual solution to producing uniformly distributed random samples which satisfy a constraint is rejection sampling: uniformly distributed random samples are produced, and any which don't satisfy the constraint are rejected. This method is `O(n)` but the constant is proportional to the inverse of the probability of the constraint being satisfied.

In the case of bridge hands with 12 or more HCPs, the probability of the constraint being satisfied is approximately 35%, so slightly fewer than three hands need to be generated on average to find one which satisfies the constraint. That's probably acceptable. If you were trying to generate hands with 20 or more HCP (probability 1.4%), you might want to try something less precise, although even there you'll only need to generate 70 hands on average, and generating a hand should be quite fast.

The simplest way to generate a bridge hand is to use reservoir sampling, which in this case will require 13 small random numbers to produce each hand. Using a standard 64-bit PRNG (such as the Mersenne twister), you could extract 10 6-bit random numbers from each PRNG iteration. (This will work with the Mersenne twister, where the bits are uncorrelated. Don't try it with the C `rand` function.)

Comment: Ok thanks, this is the fast enough and simple solution; it is as complicated as I need to make it for the speed factor.

Comment: One minor quibble - we can always generate hands such that the constraint of 12 high card points or more is satisfied by construction. Shuffle the 16 honour cards, assign the first honours to the South hand until the constraint is satisfied. Assign all subsequent cards at random to one of the four hands until all are dealt. Fill South’s hand with non-honour cards drawn at random until you have 13 cards.

Comment: @AlDante: the challenge isn't to create a hand with 12 or more HCP, which is trivial. The challenge is to produce random hands *uniformly distributed* in the universe of qualifying hands, which your procedure does not achieve (it only produces hands with between 12 and 15 HCP, for example.) There are not so many possible arrangements of honour cards in bridge hands, so an analytic solution is possible. But rejection sampling is very easy to code, and certainly fast enough if the criterion is not too uncommon.

Comment: I stand corrected - thank you. I would still approach the problem by dividing up the honour cards separately, reducing your rejection sampling to a sample size of 16 rather than 52. 

Not important, but my procedure generates a single hand with any satisfiable point count. If the constraint is a minimum of 12 HCP, and the first random honours are SA HK HJ DQ DK, then the constraint is satisfied after 5 cards. The remaining 11 honours are distributed at random to each hand - so South could potentially end up with another 8 honours. My apologies for not making this clear.

Answer (score 1):

NP-complete or not, the numbers work out so that it's possible to generate deals reasonably efficiently even if all four hands' total p values are specified to be a rare outcome.

One generation strategy is as follows. Given p values for all four hands, compute, for each of the 2^16 = 65,536 subsets of high cards, how many possibilities exist given that East-West together hold that subset. Using `BigInteger` arithmetic, generate a random subset according to the number of possibilities, then divide up East-West's high cards between East and West at random and divide up North-South's high cards between North and South at random and deal out the rest of the cards.

Given a subset `EW` specifying the high cards that East-West hold, sum, over each acceptable subset `E` of `EW` specifying the high cards that East holds, the quantity `(26 - |EW|) choose (13 - |E|)`, i.e., the number of ways to split the low cards between East and West given that it's known which ones are held by East-West. Do the same calculation for North-South.

For each choice of `EW`, the number of ways to divide the low cards between East-West and North-South is `(36 choose (26 - |EW|))`. The sampling weight of `EW` should be this quantity times the number of splits for East-West times the number of splits for North-South.

The program will have to work through on the order of 3^16 = 43,046,721 possibilities, which is a lot but not really that many for a computer. Here's a completely untuned Python prototype that takes about a minute to complete. I expect that, with a better Java implementation, it would take a fraction of a second.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import combinations
from math import factorial
from random import randrange


Card = namedtuple('Card', ('rank', 'suit'))
ranks = {'A', 'K', 'Q', 'J', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2'}
suits = ['S', 'H', 'D', 'C']
cards = {Card(rank, suit) for rank in ranks for suit in suits}


def p_value(card):
    return {'A': 4, 'K': 3, 'Q': 2, 'J': 1}.get(card.rank, 0)


high_cards = {card for card in cards if p_value(card)}


def binomial(n, k):
    return factorial(n) // (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k))


def sample_count2(ns_high_cards, n_p, s_p):
    assert n_p + s_p == sum(map(p_value, ns_high_cards))
    sample = None
    count = 0
    for k in range(min(len(ns_high_cards), len(cards) // 4) + 1):
        for n_high_cards in map(set, combinations(ns_high_cards, k)):
            if sum(map(p_value, n_high_cards)) != n_p:
                continue
            s_high_cards = ns_high_cards - n_high_cards
            assert sum(map(p_value, s_high_cards)) == s_p
            added_count = binomial(len(cards) // 2 - len(ns_high_cards), len(cards) // 4 - len(n_high_cards))
            if not added_count:
                continue
            count += added_count
            if randrange(count) < added_count:
                sample = (n_high_cards, s_high_cards)
    return (sample, count)


def sample_count(n_p, e_p, s_p, w_p):
    assert n_p + e_p + s_p + w_p == sum(map(p_value, high_cards))
    sample = None
    count = 0
    for k in range(min(len(high_cards), len(cards) // 2) + 1):
        for ns_high_cards in map(set, combinations(high_cards, k)):
            if sum(map(p_value, ns_high_cards)) != n_p + s_p:
                continue
            ew_high_cards = high_cards - ns_high_cards
            assert e_p + w_p == sum(map(p_value, ew_high_cards))
            ns_sample, ns_count = sample_count2(ns_high_cards, n_p, s_p)
            ew_sample, ew_count = sample_count2(ew_high_cards, e_p, w_p)
            added_count = binomial(len(cards) - len(high_cards), len(cards) // 2 - len(ns_high_cards)) * ns_count * ew_count
            if not added_count:
                continue
            count += added_count
            if randrange(count) < added_count:
                n_sample, s_sample = ns_sample
                e_sample, w_sample = ew_sample
                sample = (n_sample, e_sample, s_sample, w_sample)
    return (sample, count)


print(sample_count(15, 10, 10, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Who cares if it is NP-complete?  This special case is still doable.

You can do a standard dynamic programming solution to count the number of hands that meet your condition, and then revert that to generate a random solution.  As you proceed forward through the hand, your states are the counts of remaining cards of each value.  (There are only 256 possible states per card position, so this is quite doable.)

See [all solutions to change making with dynamic programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534431/all-solutions-to-change-making-with-dynamic-programming/25535846#25535846) for the idea of how to revert a dp solution to pick random examples.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at Hans van Staverens program, Dealer. Dealer uses a C-like syntax to define hands, e.g.

```
condition shape(north, any 4333 + any 4423) and hcp(north)>=13
```

defines the North hand to be 4333 with any four card suit, or any fashion of 4432 distribution (i.e to be of no trump type) and to hold at least 13 high card points.

Dealer is obviously not intended to be used for dealing cards for tournaments, but this caveat bears repeating, and Hans' program "BigDeal" covers that area separately.

[Dealer on Henk Uiterwaals Home Page](https://henku.home.xs4all.nl/software/dealer.html)

[Hans van Staverens home page. Scroll down for BigDeal](https://sater.home.xs4all.nl/)

Answer (score 0):

A semi-generative method would be the following:
Produce a random sequence of the 16 honours. Pick a hand NESW at random. Assign honours from the honours sequence until the minimum point count for the hand is reached. Repeat for the remaining hands, randomly chosen, as long as the minimum point counts can be satisfied. If all hands satisfied, distribute remaining honours, if any, at random among each of the four hands. If not, reject and repeat with a new random sequence of honours.

Complete the hands by filling up with non honours to 13 cards, chosen and distributed at random to each of the four hands.

NB: This is only a solution to the problem as posed - generate hands with a given minimum point count. A general solution is Dealer from Hans van Staveren. It also only terminates if the conditions are mutually satisfiable.