# finding all sets of a list that add to certain nmber with dynamic programming

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

I am trying to fully understand dynamic programming so I have taken the normal subset sum problem a little further and I am trying to see if I can print out all of the subsets that add to a certain number.  As of now I have done it recursively, but I would like to figure out how to do this dynamically.  Any help is appreciated.  Here is what I have now:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.schemagen.xmlschema.List;



public class subsetSum {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
          ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          list.add(1);
          list.add(3);
          list.add(4);
          list.add(0);
          printSublists(list, list, 4, true, 0);
        }

        public static Integer sum(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
             Integer sum= 0; 
             for (Integer i:list)
                 sum = sum + i;
             return sum;
        }

        public static void printSublists(ArrayList<Integer> list, ArrayList<Integer> list2, int n, boolean walkRight, int level) {

          if (sum(list2) == n)
             System.out.println(list2);

          if (list2.size() == 1)
             return;

          if (walkRight) 
            printSublists(list, new ArrayList<Integer>(list2.subList(0, list2.size()-1)), n, walkRight, level+1);

          walkRight = false;

          printSublists(list, new ArrayList<Integer>(list2.subList(1, list2.size())), n, walkRight, level+1);
        }
}
```

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25535846/585411 for an explanation of the principle behind how to solve this.

Comment: @btilly, I understand the concept and I've been attempting the process but I cannot figure out the actual code to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

Step 1.  Create classes with the following information available:

```
previousStateTransition:
    previousSum
    nextAddedElementIndex
    countOfWaysHere

sumState:
    currentSum
    countOfWaysHere
    isInitial
    previousStateTransitions (array of previousStateTransition objects ordered by nextAddedElementIndex)
```

Step 2: Implement your DP algorithm, populating the above objects.  (This will require a `HashMap` mapping the current value to the appropriate `sumState` object.

Step 3: Implement your recursive function that starts with a `sumState` object and finds all the ways of having gotten there.  Be careful as you go backwards to keep track of the `nextAddedElementIndex` and to stop walking `previousSumTransitions` when you reach or exceed the last element that is part of the current sum.

Note, both objects include a `countOfWaysHere`.  At the end, the `sumState` objects have the count of ways to this eventual final sum, while the `previousSumTransition` objects let you know the counts of ways that you could have gotten to the current sum within the first `k` elements.

Make sure to test it!